# is their any code for angular deployment ? where the refresh of the url doesn't shows any error like internal server error on IIS?

Tags: angular, deployment

After deploying my angular application on iis the application is ready to use but ,when i want to reload the page it shows internal server error.

i have included the web config file in the published dist file ,but it won't worked for me.